# Can Ethereum & Solidity implicitly check integer sizes to prevent truncation?

Tags: solidity

I have a contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract CollegeAdmin {
    uint8 public studentAge=18;
    uint16 public studentIncome=15000;
    uint8 public studentScore=4;
    uint8 public studentAttendance=96;
    event changedAge(uint age);
    function setAge(uint8 age) public {
        studentAge = age;
        changedAge(age);
    }
}
```

When I run:

```
> con.setAge(256)
"0x011189b35ac24e40f9ead0ce8062a76a0a1cad81e00b2f6fee8e43028e34cc11"
```

I get this:

```
> eth.getStorageAt(con.address,0)
"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060043a9800"
```

The `00` at the end is the studentAge. It has apparently overflowed and then truncated 100 to 00 due to the unit8 definition.

But my question, can solidity implicitly address this problem in the setter by throwing an error for larger numbers than the storage definition allows? Or does the code need to explicitly check the size of the number and then handle an error if the number is too big?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider this a bug in web3.js. It should raise an error if you pass 256 for a parameter of type `uint8`.

Comment: I guess the solution is to explicitly check the value of argument against allowed limits.